# XPages Standard Icons are not loading with oneuiv3.0.2 theme

Tags: xpages

I am extending theme oneuiv3.0.2 on domino server 9.0.1 with FP 2

```
<theme extends="oneuiv3.0.2" />
```

Theme load fine, but the images are not loading.
img tag source are pointing in format as : '/xsp/.ibmxspres/.oneuiv3/oneui/css/images/blank.gif'. 
Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the issue here:
Initially theme name I have given was "oneuiv3" and it is extending theme "oneuiv3.0.2".
Image src URL was taking the my theme name and that might be the cause of missing images.
I have renamed theme name to "oneuiv3.0.2", and all images are working fine now. 
Now I can see URL changed to: /xsp/.ibmxspres/.oneuiv302/oneui/css/images/blank.gif

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the "xsp" part, so it's just "/.ibmxspres/.oneuiv3/oneui/css/images/blank.gif" instead

Comment: source of the image is auto generated. I do not see any option to amend this src url.

Comment: Just to clarify two things: are you using a browser or the Notes Client to access the application? Do you have any [XPages Extension Library](https://extlib.openntf.org/) installed?

Comment: We have not installed any ext lib, it is part of domino 9.0.1. XSP properties include XPage Libraries "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" selected.
Applications are being accessed thru web browsers only.